# Mustache.js render first call not working on ie11

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Mustache.js, and on trying to render the first time I run my application, it does not work(with no errors) on IE11.

*var element = $(Mustache.render(template.asset, item));*

On refreshing the page (F5) it works.
Also on other browsers, like Chrome and Firefox it always works.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Do you have any console errors?

Comment: Try to append the template on your injection tag: $('#template-goes-here').append(template), then on your render function just do: $('#template-goes-here').html(template)